Why does the ProGuard rule expand my APK size to be even larger than the jar itself？
I have finished a very simple demo just includes a button and textview.If I enable these two switch with empty proguard-rules.pro.The apk's size will be 1.5M.
build.gradle
buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        isShrinkResources = true
        proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        signingConfig = signingConfigs["release"]
    }
}

But if I add these proguard-rules content,the apk's size will be 4M.These are all content of my proguard-rules.pro.I add these specific obfuscated codes instead of using wildcard as possible as I can so that more code can be obfuscated.And they are all about my local jar,but this local jar is only 0.7M.
proguard-rules.pro
-dontwarn com.pax.neptunelite.api.NeptuneLiteUser
-keep class com.pax.neptunelite.api.NeptuneLiteUser{
    public static synchronized com.pax.neptunelite.api.NeptuneLiteUser getInstance();
    public synchronized com.pax.dal.IDAL getDal(android.content.Context);
    private com.pax.dal.IDAL loadDalDex(android.content.Context, java.lang.String);
}
-keep class com.pax.neptunelite.api.Nepcore{*;}
-keep interface com.pax.dal.IDAL{
    com.pax.dal.ISys getSys();
    com.pax.dal.IPrinter getPrinter();
    com.pax.dal.IPed getPed(com.pax.dal.entity.EPedType );
}
-keep interface com.pax.dal.IPrinter{
    int start();
    void init();
    void setGray(int);
    void spaceSet(byte , byte );
    void printStr(java.lang.String , java.lang.String);
    void step(int) ;
}
-keep interface com.pax.dal.IPed{  com.pax.dal.entity.KeyInfo queryKeyInfo(byte, byte); }
-keep interface com.pax.dal.ISys{*;}
-keep interface com.pax.dal.proxy.IDALProxy{ *; }
-keep class com.pax.dal.entity.EPedType{ *; }
-keep class com.pax.dal.entity.ETermInfoKey{ *; }
-keep class com.pax.dal.entity.KeyInfo{ *; }
-keep class com.pax.dal.exceptions.PrinterDevException{ *; }
-keep class com.pax.dal.exceptions.PedDevException{ *; }
-keep class com.pax.dal.exceptions.EPedDevException{ *; }

I can't understand why this jar is only 0.7M,after I add some obfuscate rules for this jar,apk's size can be 2.5M more.Could anyone can tell me why?Thank you a lot!
Here I add these two apk's size images.Hope to help you guys analysis
first apk's composition
second apk's composition
*As my apk's function is very easy,without any image resources.And I already remove all redundant dependency.And last I found this dex is what I must need to defuse.But As I know,obfuscating code is to reduce apk's size.And progurad-rules.pro is to let some class not to be obfuscated,so I reduce the code not to be obfuscate as less as possible.But I found the effect is little.I try to use dex2jar to convert dex to jar to see the difference,but the result codes are all obfuscated,so I can't understand.
Now I found the reason is due to this rule:
-keep class com.pax.neptunelite.api.Nepcore{*;}

because this class includes many dex,so it will larger 2.3M of my apk by loading these dex.But in other projects,there are the same rule and jar,but no larger 2.3M,just 0.2M roughly,so I still can't understand why,The one difference between my project and other projects is that my project is almost no function and little code,but other projects have many functiona and codes.Could anyone tell me why?*

Please [edit] your question and replace the screenshots of your code with the code as text. And while you're at it, you can also remove the italic markup, that is unnecessary.

Maybe because it has to keep the given classes? Also, are you making a release build in both cases?

Thank you for your advice,I have changed the format.

My jar is only 0.7M,And my given classes is only a little in it,so it must be less than 0.1M,and both cases are make a release.

Could anyone help me ,I'm indeed need help.Thanks!
